# WPF request value was not found

Tags: c#, wpf

I've been creating a WPF application using .net core 3 preview 6. I'm using MVVM pattern. When I was creating layout, using preview 5, everything was correct, but now it doesn't. I have an exception during parse XAML. I had to translate this into english. Sorry if i did any mistake.

> Message: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException : Call constructor for the type "System.Windows.Controls.TextBox" complying with bound restrictions has caused an exception. ---- System.ArgumentException : Request value "USUŃ" was not found.

I have this exception when TextBox or PasswordBox are creating.
Nowhere in the project is "USUŃ". USUŃ means DELETE.

Comment: could your show your code?

Comment: Have you tried to search "USUŃ" in the project or solution?

Comment: which part of code? There is no "USUŃ"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar problem getting a System.ArgumentException "requested value 'BILDAUF' was not found" with preview 6. Returning to preview 5 it works again. For me the exception occurs trying to get into a TextBox using the mouse ... it gets thrown before any handler is actually called, so it happens somewhere in the framework.

My gut-feeling: it could be some issue in the Culture Settings that I'm not able to pin down, most probably I'm missing some general setting at init-time. Because BILDAUF is the german name for the PAGEUP key. USUŃ should be the DELETE key (in Polish), if I'm not mistaken ...

---

I started writing this answer some time ago and was interrupted - seems my gut-feeling deserves a pat on the shoulder:
https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/684

So, if it is feasible you "could" set the CurrentUICulture to en-US - in my case this is fine with me, since I'm writing tools for a project using English as project language. The only other option I'm aware of right now is to stick with preview 5, as preview 7 will still contatin some Culture related issues as the last answer in the linked issue-thread clearly states.

Comment: Welcome to SO! If you have a similar question, you might want to post a new question and perhaps mention this one in your post. Good luck!